# How to test legacy jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, tdd, mocha.js

I'm starting to introduce TDD into an existing JavaScript/jQuery project.

Currently, I'm testing with Mocha and Chai under Grunt in a CLI shell in Emacs.

This works nicely for the parts of the code that are side-effect-free, synchronous, don't use jQuery, etc.

I've found many online articles addressing individual issues in setting up a more inclusive test environment, but I've not managed to find a good getting-started guide, without diving into the weeds of competing libraries and setups.

I don't need a "best" answer, nor anything too fancy. I don't even need mock button presses or user-input; I'm happy just testing my handler code.

Just looking for a guide or set of recommended best practices to test client-side JavaScript code where:

- The existing code uses jQuery and AJAX;
- The test environment should be running continuously;
- The test environment should be launched from my gruntfile. Or, I'd be ok moving to gulp or any other similar driver.
- Ideally, I'd like the tests to be running in an Emacs buffer. But, if need be, I'd be ok having it running in another window that I can stick in the corner of my screen;
- Tests should run reasonably fast. I want them to trigger automatically on every file save.

I think I'm describing a very vanilla set of test requirements, so I'd expect there to be common answers.  But, my search-fu must be low today because I'm not finding what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Mocha and Chai, then you already have the basics set up.

If your code under test modifies the document, you can substitute an artificial document for your tests (via `jsdom`).

If your code under test fires Ajax calls and you'd like to test them, you can use `sinon` to put a fake `XMLHttpRequest` provider. `sinon` also offers a convenient mock for `setTimeout` and the family.

If the code under test uses jQuery, then you can either separate the jQuery-dependent part, or just run jQuery on the server using the `jsdom` document. `jQuery` installs with npm easily.

---

If all of this seems not realistic enough for your purpose and you'd like a more true environment, you can have a look at `karma` - it's an automation tool that can open a browser in the background, run any tests inside and report the errors in the console. It's much slower than `mocha` but you get to run your code (and tests) in a real browser, perhaps even several browsers at the same time.

Both tools have their places, e.g. you could use `mocha` for testing vanillajs and simple DOM modification (also e.g. React components if you're into that), and resort to `karma` for writing slower, more realistic tests that depend more on real browser behaviour.

Comment: Sounds like sinon and jsdom are more the direction I want, at least for now.  I'll take a closer look at them.

Comment: Any examples or recommended tutorials on how to put the pieces together? I'm finding many tempting hints like https://gist.github.com/yairEO/d281bf017d203556f96c, but not sure yet how they play together or which are reliable.

Comment: the `mocha-jsdom` package does the dom setup for you, and sinon is straightforward to use from within `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()`.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I just found mocha-jsdom now, and am looking at it.